# Is the following question suitable for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I have a question that I would like the ask the SO community. However, I am worried that the question does not fall in the following from this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Without typing out the entire question here, I will give a quick run down.

The general essence is that I've recently begun an internship which has syphoned all of my drive/passion/motivation for anything related to computers away. In the past I know I have thoroughly enjoyed working on programming projects that allowed me to ***learn something***, actually ***think*** a little bit and ***produces something*** that is usable. Basically, I need to ask for programming ideas that fit this criteria in the hopes that I can reignite some form of passion for this industry.

I don't think my question fits any of the above points unfortunately. Which is really unfortunate because the quality and breadth of knowledge that users have in this community is amazing and I would love for that to be applied to my issue.

**Question:** Can I ask my question on SO? If not what are there any other sites/communities that I would be able to get an appropriate answer for my question?

Sorry for such an all-over-the-place question. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: No, your question sounds totally off-topic.

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for reddit, if you can find a decent corner on that site.

Comment: @MartinJames I agree, know of any quality sites that would fit?

Comment: @ivarni Thanks I was thinking the same, Ill I have look! Got any recommendations?

Comment: It is off-topic. My go-to advice when I read something like this is 1) self-reflection time. Are you sure programming is really for you if even an internship can push you this far? 2) If you still want to be a programmer, consider creating a simple video game as a hobby. Do something fun and creative.

Comment: With GitHub and Open Source there are so many projects, even many that are actively seeking help, that there is possibly one you can relate to. If not, you can always start your own. Maybe learn Android and create the next "killer" app which will make you a millionaire.

Comment: @Abra On that note, [Up For Grabs](https://up-for-grabs.net/#/) isn't a bad place to start if someone has no idea where to begin.

Comment: @Gimby So I should have pointed out that the internship is non-programming related and is at a tiny 2 person MSP. Whilst here the boss has barely been at the office so have had a lack of anything to do so have been doing a bit of programming on the side. However I feel a few things outside of the internship and the bad experience here has lead me to have a lot of trouble with motivating myself. I haven't though of making a little game but might be just what I need to reinvigorate myself. Thanks

Comment: @Abra Thank you for this, that is a good idea. I feel I need to create something that has a tangible product for me to keep motivated with it. I'll have to get thinking of some ideas! Thanks

Comment: @zcoop98 ooh thank you that site looks very helpful for finding projects that need help. Thank you

Comment: Is it one of those internships that are required to complete a higher-education degree?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes it's a part of my degree and I feel this place just gets interns in for the hell of it and have no real plan for them. With Covid they've had less work which has just exacerbated the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. That being said, valid Stack Overflow questions should [have answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/), not just ideas or opinions.

This question appears to be soliciting discussion rather than answers, so it's off topic on the entire Stack Exchange network.

You may be able to pose a question like this in chat, though.